# How to Add AdMob Interstitial Ads in my App android?

Tags: admob, interstitial

I want to Know how to add admob interstitial ads in my app , I find a lot of codes but i dont have a idea where i should put it them on my project so please help me !

Comment: Could you tell us more on which platform - you are trying to implements ads?

Comment: platform Android ,  withe eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Officially there is no way shown to add ads on with eclipse because eclipse is old way for android development rather now the focus is on ADT. So try to open/modify your project as per ADT and add Ads. After that, follow the offical documentation here from AdMob team and on the side, download the sample project which gives us a chance to see live running code and ads working properly. That is also provided on the same page Here- https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start